# MySQL Workbench stuck on loading sql editor

Tags: mysql-workbench

My workbench keeps on showing the loading dialog that says "Opening SQL editor. An SQL editor instance for 'Connection Name' is opening and should be available in a moment" but nothing happens after. The test connection is successful. I was able to access this yesterday but then, without changing anything, suddenly I can't access it anymore today. I already tried reinstalling the workbench and even the MySQL Server, but the issue still remains.

[The loading dialog that keeps showing when I attempt to open the connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTJfz.png)

I tried reinstalling the workbench and the mysql server, thinking that it will resolve the issue, but nothing happens.

Comment: How many schemas and tables do you have in your MySQL Server instance? There have been reports of extreme slowness when MySQL Workbench tries to start, because it loads metadata for all schemas and tables on startup. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53582

Comment: To be honest, I never use MySQL Workbench. It's just too buggy in many scenarios. I use command-line `mysql` client, or `mysqlsh`. Don't waste your time or grey hair with the GUI tool.

Comment: Me, either. I use PhpStorm for software editing, but I rarely use its database GUI.

Comment: I use workbench to access my online database. It is working very fine yesterday but then it stopped working now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.